# compile error in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, compilation, g++

I am  getting these errors when i compile sim_routing.cc program by this command:

```
../../bin/cxx sim_routing.cc
g++ -Wall -o sim_routing sim_routing.cxx
```

The following errors are shown:

```
../../common/priority_q.h : In member function 'bool guardedQueue<ITEM>::Validate(Const char*);
error : there are no argument to 'strcat' that depend on template parameter so a declaration of 'strcat' must be avaible.
error : <if you use -fpermissive  g++ will accept your code but allowing use of undeclared name is deprecated>
```

When i tried to change the `commom/priority_q.h` file, it shows it is read only file, so changes cannot be made.

How can these errors be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but you could possibly try to include

```
#include <cstring>
```

*before* you include that `priority_q.h` file in your code. That should bring `strcat`'s declaration in scope before that template is processed.